# Не закрывающееся окно открытия Visual studio через Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio-2019

Когда я открывал код через Visual studio у меня не было подсказок. Нашел решение назначить в "External Script Editor" visual studio (было "Open by file extension"). Поставил, подсказки появились, как и сама проблема. Создаю проекты в Unity, создаю файл с кодом C#, все нормально, ошибок нет. Решаю открыть файл, Unity открывает его через Visual Studio 2019. После открытия остается окно открытия Visual Studio (скрин 1). Окно не пропадает, мешает работать. Даже после закрытия VS, это окно остается и продолжает что то открывать.
[image: Каждый раз останавливается на этом моменте].
Пробовал:
1)копаться в настройках Unity, по советам из интернета
Заметил что в настройках General нет пункта "Code Optimization On Startup", хотя должен бть судя по этому сайту: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-and-known-issues-visual-studio-tools-for-unity
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2)переустанавливать полностью visual studio и unity
3)пытался закрыть его через диспетчер задач. Там его просто нет. окно которое нигде не отображается, кроме моего экрана
Ничего не помогло, надеюсь есть знатоки, которые знают решение

Comment: может быть тебе просто подождать? Попробуй подождать час, если не исчезнет, то это очередной баг юнити

Comment: Хочу добавить, что это окно стало появляться после того, как я включил подсказки. Если перед открытием файла с кодом изменить настройки "External Script Editor" на "Open by file extension", то он спокойно все открывает и не создает лишних окон.

Comment: В общем проблему я решил, но очень сомнительно.
Пытался через совместимость в свойствах VS и Unity. Этого раздела у меня не было. Поискал решение, сделал все правильно, все равно ничего. В итоге забил на это решение.
Видел что кто то через перезапуск приложения или отключение через диспетчер задач решает. Мне это тоже не помогло.

Comment: В итоге как я решил: открываю в Unity свой проект. Открываю отдельно VS (кнопка "продолжить без кода"). Открываю папку с проектом и перетягиваю файл *.sln в VS. В итоге окно не открывается, подсказки есть.
Если у вас не появиться код, перетащите персонально его: у меня он был в папке "Assets". Тогда код должен появиться со всеми подсказками. Толкните если появиться рабочее решение